# Упражнения по теме делегаты и события c#

Tags: c#

Оказалась, делегаты и события достаточна сложная для меня тема. Я разбирал данную тему по книге Шилдта, еще читал книгу Кристиан Нейгел, Билл Ивьен, Джей Глинн, Карли Уотсон, Морган Скиннер. Некоторое понимание сложилось. Хочу улучшить и закрепить свое понимание на практике. Поисковик не нашел мне упражнений по данной теме. Прошу помочь придумать мне учебные программы, которые помогу понять лучше всего эту тему. Упражнения должны быть связанны только с консольными программами, так как с gui я не знаком. Разбираться с gui буду позже.

Answer (score 1):

Напишите "пинг-понг":

- 2 класса Ping и Pong
- один уведомляет другого, о том, что "произошёл пинг", другой - о том, что "произошёл понг",
- одна пара объектов "играют" между собой, другая пара - между собой и т.д.

и выводить на консоль соответсвующие сообщения, что-то вроди такого:

1. Ping received Pong.
2. Pong received Ping.
3. Ping received Pong.
4. Pong received Ping.
5. Ping received Pong.